# SharePoint 2013 Give a person access to all restricted files/folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, item-level-permissions

I need to grant a person the access to all restricted files/folders on the site or site collection without adding the person as one of the site collection Admin or site owner.

I tried to give the person the **Full control** access, but it is not working, he is still not able to access to the restricted folders.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the restricted files/folder on which item level permissions are enabled or in case you have break the inheritance on the sub-site, giving **Full Access** control will not a work.

In order to access the restricted files/folders/sub-sites user should be **Site Collection Administrator**.

SharePoint Administration Roles and SharePoint Permissions are explained in below articles:

1. [Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).
2. [Understanding SharePoint Permissions](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/12/26/understanding-sharepoint-permissions/).

Answer (score 1):

Check if "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" is enabled at site collection level. If yes, disable it. Then test again.